# MS Access SQL Dropdown Formatting

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to get my combobox to populate based off of what the previous combo box selection. Right now it is set to Query after the first combobox is updated.

```
Dim cbClientQuery As String

cbClientQuery = "SELECT [Client_PR] FROM [Process_Table] WHERE [Process_PR] = me.cb_Process.Value"

Me.cb_Client.RowSource = cbClientQuery
Me.cb_Client.Requery
```

But when I make a selection from the first combobox, I click the second combobox and it opens a message box titled "Enter Parameter" and message "me.cb_Process.Vaule" then a textbox with ok or cancel. I'm sure it is just syntax, but could I get a little assistance with this please?

Comment: You want to update the Client.RowSource in the AfterUpdate() section of the previous ComboBox. Which class did you put this VBA code in?

Comment: You are saying `WHERE [Process_PR] = me.cb_Process.Value` -- try concatenating the sql string to the value instead -- `where field = '" & field & "'` or look into using parameterized queries.

Comment: I have all of that code within that section. (In the cbProcess combo box AfterUpdate() section)

Comment: That means it can't find anything called `me.cb_Process.Value`, so it wants you to enter a value manually.

Comment: @sgeddes You are correct! Thanks for the help!